# When a function takes an rvalue reference, what is the type of that variable within the function?

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, lvalue-to-rvalue

This is a question of terminology. If I have this:

```
#include <vector>

void g(std::vector<int>&& arg);

void f0(std::vector<int>&& v) {
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(v), std::vector<int>&&>::value); // Looks like v is an rvalue reference.
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype((v)), std::vector<int>&>::value);
    static_assert(std::is_same<std::decay<decltype(v)>::type, std::vector<int>>::value);
    return g(std::move(v)); // Fine.
}
```

then what type is `v`? If you are talking about calling `f0`, you'd say "`f0` takes an rvalue reference" (right?) but within `f0`, `v` isn't an rvalue reference, or else the `std::move` wouldn't be required? Right? But the `static_assert` showed that it is an rvalue, right?

Similarly:

```
void f1(std::vector<int>&& v) {
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(v), std::vector<int>&&>::value);
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype((v)), std::vector<int>&>::value);
    static_assert(std::is_same<std::decay<decltype(v)>::type, std::vector<int>>::value);
    return g(v); // Error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type 'std::vector<int>&&' to lvalue of type 'std::vector<int>'.
    // So is v just a std::vector<int>?
}
```

Local rvalue references act the same way:

```
void f2(std::vector<int>&& v) {
    std::vector<int>&& vv = std::move(v);
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(vv), decltype(v)>::value, "They are the same decltype. So being an argument isn't magic.");
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(vv), std::vector<int>&&>::value);
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype((vv)), std::vector<int>&>::value);
    static_assert(std::is_same<std::decay<decltype(vv)>::type, std::vector<int>>::value);
    return g(vv); // Error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type 'std::vector<int>&&' to lvalue of type 'std::vector<int>'
}
```

What is the correct terminology to describe the type of `v`? Is it correct to say `f0` takes an rvalue reference? If `v` is an rvalue reference, what's the terminology to say that an rvalue reference can't be used to call a function taking an rvalue reference?

Comment: Basically, named rvalue references (type) are lvalues (value category).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **declared type** of the variable named `v` is `std::vector<int>&&`. This type is read "*rvalue reference to* `std::vector`".

The name `v` can appears in an **expression**. Expressions never have reference type [[expr.type]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.type#1). But expressions have a [*value category*](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval). When the name `v` appears in an expression as in `v[0]`, the subexpression `v` has type `std::vector<int>` and its value category is *lvalue*. This is the case of almost all [*id-expression*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id#unqual-2.sentence-7) (expressions that are just a name).

`decltype(v)` gives the declared type of the variable `v`.

`decltype(expression)` gives :

- a lvalue-reference to the type of `expression` if `expression` is a lvalue,
- a rvalue-reference to the type of `expression` if `expression` is a xvalue,
- the type of `expression` if `expression` is a prvalue.

More details are given in [[dcl.dcl]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.decltype#1).

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing types with value categories which, in your defence, is extraordinarily easy to do.

Yes, the function takes an argument of type "rvalue reference to `std::vector<int>`". This reference can be initialised from an rvalue expression of type `std::vector<int>`, at the callsite.

The type of the expression `v` inside the function, when you start to try to use it, is not `std::vector<int>&&`; the reference sort of "decays". That's just part of the machinery of how references work. (The `decltype` there is a bit of an oddity in this regard.) For all intents and purposes, you end up with an *lvalue* expression of type `std::vector<int>`. Anyway, at this point the type is sort of irrelevant; the point is that the name `v` is an lvalue, and to make it into an rvalue again you need `std::move`.

> But the static_assert showed that it is an rvalue, right?

Nope. "rvalue reference" describes kinds of types. "rvalue" is a value category. You might wonder why they chose such confusing terminology. So do I.